# Not Receiving Parse Push Notifications on Android in Custom BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, parse-platform

I can successfully send a push notification using Parse with the following data, but can't receive the message in my custom Broadcast Receiver. Following the Parse Android notification guide: https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving/Android. Any help would be appreciated!

Sending the push:

```
ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> userQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
                userQuery.whereContainedIn("user", arg0);

                JSONObject data= null;
                try {
                    data = new JSONObject("{\"title\" : \"Hush!\"," +
                                            "\"intent\" : \"ChatWindowActivity\"," +
                                            "\"action\" : \"com.hush.UPDATE_STATUS\"," +
                                            "\"chatId\" :" + getObjectId() + "}");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
                push.setQuery(userQuery);
                push.setData(data);
                push.setMessage("One of your friends wants to chat...");
                push.sendInBackground();
```

AndroidManifest settings:

```
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.hush.HushPushReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.hush.UPDATE_STATUS" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver
    android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <category android:name="com.hush" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Custom Push Receiver:

```
package com.hush;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.JSONException; 
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver; import android.content.Context; 
import     android.content.Intent; import android.util.Log; import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;

public class HushPushReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "DEBUG"; 

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  Toast.makeText(context, "Push received!!!!.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(intent);
try {
  String action = intent.getAction();
  String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

  Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action + " on channel " + channel + " with:");
  Iterator itr = json.keys();
  while (itr.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) itr.next();
    Log.d(TAG, "..." + key + " => " + json.getString(key));
  }
} catch (JSONException e) {
  Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

}
}

Comment: @N see your blogs and it's awesome.

Comment: Can you post your full manifest?

Answer (score 7):

Figured it out based on this push notification demo! https://github.com/ahiraz/pushNotificationDemo

Comment: Attention: To run sample from link above and see how it works you have to enable "client push" notifications in parse dashboard. You have to do it generally if u want send notifiactions from app and see results

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file you are using

> com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver

instead of that use your custom broadcastreciver , in you case simple change > com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver to

> com.yourpackagename.IncomingReceiver

Dont test broadcastreciver in simulator it will not work so check in andorid device

See this repo which uses a custom broadcastreciver for parse push notification
https://github.com/srini-hashinc/IIYO/tree/master