# android-Disable notification when I get a parse notification within BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-notifications

I send notifications from parse.com to my users . I get this message in a BroadcastReceiver and do other jobs there .

The problem is that I get notification with each message and I don't want my users to see this notifications . I send json data from parse.com and usrrs shouldn't see something like these .

This is the broadcaseRecevier code:

```
public class ParseBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
JSONArray contacts = null;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
    String json = extra.getString("com.parse.Data");
    JSONObject jObject;

    try {
        jObject = new JSONObject(json);
        //jObject.optString("alert")
        Log.v("this",jObject.getString("alert").replace("data:",""));
        JSONObject jsons = new JSONObject(jObject.getString("alert").replace("data:",""));

        String strTel = jsons.getString("tel");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.v("this","error "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

I'm sure it comes to this class.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to have Parse generate a notification when a broadcast is received, you can create a custom notification.

Looks like this SO is a good example of this: [Not Receiving Parse Push Notifications on Android in Custom BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118383/not-receiving-parse-push-notifications-on-android-in-custom-broadcastreceiver)

Basically the idea is to send and 'action' property with the JSON, containing the name of an Intent. This intent is then fired (sending of a broadcast) once the push is received. Then your custom broadcast receiver, listening to the 'action' name, can handle the received JSON any way you like.

Took a quick look over the documentation at: https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#options/Android and noticed that the 'action' parameter is no longer mentioned, but it is indeed still supported, as I am currently relying on it.

If any parse.com employees sees this, it would be nice with a comment on the missing 'action' parameter in the documentation of push notifications.

**Update:**

I have not testet it myself, but the documentation at: https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving-responding/Android section: `Managing the Push Lifecycle` implies that you can:

- Subclass ParsePushBroadcastReceiver
- And to avoid default notification generation either:

  - Rename 'alert' to something else, e.g. 'data'
  - Or quote:

> One might override onPushReceive to trigger a background operation for "silent" pushes and then delegate to super for all other pushes

**Update2:**

Opened a question on the Google Group discussion for Parse and found that the 'action' to Intent approach is deprecated (which is why it is not documented anymore).

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/NLT64ObeaBY